# how to inform user about upgrade version of software in windows phone 'mango' programmatically

Tags: windows-phone

I am developing an Application(In windows phone' Mango') where in I need to notify about the user(our application user) about the  upgrade version of my application ,how can I do this?

Plz help

Thanks!

Sneha

Comment: The Marketplace should do that for you, when you push the new version out.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Phone Marketplace application will take care of notifying the users when an upgraded version of your application is available, so you don't have to.

Having said that, if you still did want to do this, you could do something simple like host a text-file on a webserver that holds the currnet version number of your application, and then from your application you could periodically connect to the site to determine whether the user is running the latest version.